Morphisms in the category of elements
I'm confused about the direction of morphisms in the category of elements.
Grothendieck's definition: Given a presheaf $P \colon C^{op} \to Set$, a morphism from $(a, x)$ to $(b, y)$ (where $x \in P a$ and $y \in P b$) is an arrow $f \colon a \to b$ in $C$, such that $(P f) y = x$.
The nLab definition is for a co-presheaf $F \colon C \to Set$, and a morphism from $(a, x)$ to $(b, y)$ is also an arrow $f \colon a \to b$. That would suggest that for a presheaf, we should take an arrow $b \to a$ as a morphism.
However, Emily Riehl uses $a \to b$ in both the category of elements for the presheaf and the copresheaf. This seems to break the symmetry between categories and their opposites, favoring the former over the latter. It also creates a conundrum about how to define the category of elements for a profunctor $C^{op} \times C \to Set$.

There are two constructions: the covariant category of elements of a copresheaf $C \to \mathbf{Set}$ and the contravariant category of elements of a presheaf $C^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$; they both come with a covariant projection to $C$, which dictates the direction of the morphisms. Riehl defines both in CTiC (the covariant one in 2.4.1 and the contravariant one in 2.4.2). No two authors seem to agree on the notation, though; some denote contravariant with a subscript and covariant with a superscript and some do the opposite.

This still doesn't answer the question of what to do with a profunctor. Parallel arrows, or twisted arrows?

Your confusion is understandable, as you can define the morphisms either way. For me the easiest way to understand this is through the most general form which is for profunctors $R : C^{op} \times D \to \textrm{Set}$. We can take the graph or tabulator of $R$, which is a category equipped with a projection functor $p : \textrm{Gr}(R) \to C \times D$ (no ops on either side) which is defined as follows:

Objects are triples $(c \in C_0, d \in D_0, r \in R(c,d))$
Morphisms from $(c,d,r)$ to $(c',d',r')$ are pairs of morphisms $f : C(c,c')$ and $g:D(d,d')$ satisfying $R(f,d')(r') = R(c,g)(r)$. We can visualize this as a kind of "heterogeneous commutative square".

with obvious identity and composition.
Then you can see the two different forms of the Grothendieck construction as instances of this graph construction by viewing the input as a functor $C^{op} \times 1 \to \textrm{Set}$ or $1^{op} \times C \to \textrm{Set}$. In the former you get a projection to $C \times 1$ and the latter you get a projection to $1 \times C$ which are of course both equivalent to $C$.

I think the condition on morphisms doesn't quite typecheck

fixed it, thanks

Than the next question is, what's the category of elements for a bifunctor $C \times D \to Set$, and so on. Is there a general recipe?

For a general functor of many variables $F : C_1^\mathrm{op} \times \cdots \times C_n^\mathrm{op} \times D_1 \times \cdots \times D_m \to Set$, you can treat this as a special case of the above by writing the domain as $(C_1 \times \cdots \times C_n)^\mathrm{op} \times (D_1 \times \cdots \times D_m)$

@BartoszMilewski oops forgot to ping

What if I find out later that my $D_3$ was actually $Set^{op}$? Do I start over?

Surely there is no right or wrong answer and it ultimately depends on what you want to do with the construction.

@BartoszMilewski you the mathematician must choose which construction you want. We can view any functor $F : C \to Set$ as either covariant in $C$ or contravariant in $C^op$. You can think of this as a "choice of basis/orientation" for the category, and the output of the Grothendieck construction depends on this choice.

@MaxNew : The analogy doesn't work if the category in question can be decomposed into a product of multiple categories. Then you can choose different bases for different parts of it. And the decomposition itself is not unique. So can you just reverse arrows willy-nilly?
